# Docker compose run migrations on django web application + postgres db

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Hi I am having issues running migrations on postgres db container from django.

Here is my docker-compose file

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file:
    - ./.env
  environment:
    - DEBUG=1
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  build: ./postgres
  env_file: .env
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

The directory structure is below. [image]

The .env file defines the Postgres DB , user name and password

```
DB_NAME=test
DB_USER=test
DB_PASS=test!
DB_SERVICE=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=test
POSTGRES_DB=test
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test!
```

When I run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d` nginx, postgres and web containers start. The postgres startup (default) creates the db, user and password. The django startup container installs requirements.txt and starts the django server (everything looks good).

On running makemigrations

`docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py  makemigrations polls`
I get the following output

`Migrations for 'polls':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Choice
    - Create model Question
    - Add field question to choice`

But when I run

`docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py showmigrations polls`
the output is.

`polls
 (no migrations)`

on running 
`docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py migrate --fake polls`
the output I see

`Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: (none)
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.`

The tables are not created in postgres. What am I doing wrong ? Sorry for the long post but I wanted to put all the details here.

Comment: Do you only have one app or not?

Comment: Have you configured Django to use postgresql in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Yes the Django is configured to use postgressql in settings.py .

Comment: @Aison Yes there is only one app

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: try run docker-compose logs to see the log

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Django version 1.9.2